# jQuery fade elements from one class to another, on hover

Tags: jquery, css, effects, fadein, jquery-effects

can this be done?

for eg.

```
.class1{
  background-image:(whatever.jpg)
  color: #fff;
}

.class2{
  background-image:(whatever2.jpg)
  color: #999;
}
```

can I fade all elements that have class1 to class2 when the mouse is over the element, and back to class1 when mouse is out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give both the same absolute position, using fadeIn() and fadeOut() will have this effect (attached to onmouseover and onmouseout).

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to use a plugin, you can do the following:

```
$(".class1").hover(
function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("class1").addClass("class2").fadeIn('fast');
    });
},
function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("class2").addClass("class1").fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at [jQuery UI's extension to `addClass`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/). It allows a duration parameter to give the possibility of animation.

Here, I think you want to do something like this:

```
$('.class1').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('class2', 800);
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('class2', 800);
});
```

Obviously you'll need to install jQuery UI for this.

Comment: can it animate background images? on jquery UI there are only a few css properties listed in animation

Answer (score 4):

I think [this plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class) is what you are looking for. It allows you to animate between classes. For example:

```
$('.class1').animateToClass('.class2', 1000);
```

Comment: +1 This is also how I understood the question. Note that for color animations you would need either jQuery UI or a plugin like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Comment: @Alexandra So you downloaded the plugin I linked to. Included it just below where you included jQuery and then used the code I showed as an example in conjunction with something like @lonesomeday posted? Because it should work fine, unless you are using jQuery 1.5 which may or may not work with this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation:

```
      $(this).fadeOut("fast"); or $(this).hide();
      $(this).removeClass('css1').addClass('css2');
 $(this).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

By providing Jquery hover() with the handlerIn and handlerOut functions as [documented here](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) you can easily handle the mouse in and mouse out events. Next, take a look at [Jquery UI switchClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/) to easily switch between two classes in a clean way. Lastly, adding fadeIn() makes all of this a clean transition.

```
$("div.class1").hover(
 function(){$("div").switchClass("class1", "class2").fadeIn(800);},
 function(){$("div").switchClass("class2", "class1").fadeIn(800);}
);
```

[Working CodePen](https://codepen.io/katrpilar/pen/VENBJB)

Answer (score -2):

i think this might be help full to you....

```
$('.class1').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('class2');
 });
```

Comment: Using jQuery's toggleClass method toggles one class on and off an element. It has nothing to do with two classes and toggling between them.